# Swift : can not call an class method of an Objective-C class

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am willing to get a reference to an instance of an Objective-C class by calling, from Swift, one of its class initialiser functions.

The class I am willing to use is AWSMobileAnalytics, available at https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/AWSCore/MobileAnalytics/include/AWSMobileAnalytics.h

It defines a initialiser like this

```
@interface AWSMobileAnalytics : NSObject

+ (instancetype)mobileAnalyticsForAppId:(NSString *)appId;

...
@end
```

My code is

```
let ma = AWSMobileAnalytics.mobileAnalytics(forAppId: appId)
```

(and I tried many variant of it).  The compiler says

`Type AWSMobileAnalytics.Type has no member 'mobileAnalytics'`

Any suggestion ?

Seb

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have imported the framework in bridging header.You need to call like this

```
    let ma = ViewController.mobileAnalyticsForAppId("abc")
```

Comment: Or AWSMobileAnalytics(forAppId: appId)

Comment: @Shuo not `AWSMobileAnalytics(forAppId: appId)`  the intilizer only skip part having before `With`.So this your suggestion will not work.

Comment: You can also rely on auto-complete -- type AWSMobileAnalytics( and let Xcode suggest the rest for you.

Comment: Thank you cadaster for your proposal.  Having triple checked my bridging header and your suggestion, compiler now returns "mobileAnalyticsForAppId is not available, use object construction AWSMobileAnalytics(forAppId:)" Code completion is not providing any suggestion, otherwise I would not have posted the question :-)

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use a Bridging Header.

Just import it like this in your AppDelegate:

```
import AWSMobileAnalytics
```

then

```
AWSMobileAnalytics(forAppId: "yourID")
```